# Windows Media Player plugin for Firefox under Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, windows-media-player, plugins

i'm working under Ubuntu 10.04, with Firefox 3.6. Windows Media Player (WMP) Plugin is installed:

```
Windows Media Player Plug-in

    Datei: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/gecko-mediaplayer-wmp.so
    Version: 
    Gecko Media Player 0.9.9.2

    Video Player Plug-in for QuickTime, RealPlayer and Windows Media Player streams using MPlayer

MIME-Typ    Beschreibung    Endungen    Aktiviert
application/asx     Media Files     *   Ja
video/x-ms-asf-plugin   Media Files     *   Ja
video/x-msvideo     AVI     avi,*   Ja
video/msvideo   AVI     avi,*   Ja
application/x-mplayer2  Media Files     *   Ja
application/x-ms-wmv    Microsoft WMV video     wmv,*   Ja
video/x-ms-asf  Media Files     asf,asx,*   Ja
video/x-ms-asx  Media Files     asx,*   Ja
video/x-ms-wm   Media Files     wm,*    Ja
video/x-ms-wmv  Microsoft WMV video     wmv,*   Ja
audio/x-ms-wmv  Windows Media   wmv,*   Ja
video/x-ms-wmp  Windows Media   wmp,*   Ja
application/x-ms-wmp    Windows Media   wmp,*   Ja
video/x-ms-wvx  Windows Media   wvx,*   Ja
audio/x-ms-wax  Windows Media   wax,*   Ja
audio/x-ms-wma  Windows Media   wma,*   Ja
application/x-drm-v2    Windows Media   asx,*   Ja
audio/wav   Microsoft wave file     wav,*   Ja
audio/x-wav     Microsoft wave file     wav,*   Ja
```

and also the mplayer plugin

```
mplayerplug-in is now gecko-mediaplayer 0.9.9.2

    Datei: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/gecko-mediaplayer.so
    Version: 
    Gecko Media Player 0.9.9.2

    Video Player Plug-in for QuickTime, RealPlayer and Windows Media Player streams using MPlayer

MIME-Typ    Beschreibung    Endungen    Aktiviert
audio/x-mpegurl     MPEG Playlist   m3u     Ja
video/mpeg  MPEG    mpg,mpeg    Ja
audio/mpeg  MPEG    mpg,mpeg    Ja
video/x-mpeg    MPEG    mpg,mpeg    Ja
video/x-mpeg2   MPEG2   mpv2,mp2ve  Ja
audio/mpeg  MPEG    mpg,mpeg    Ja
audio/x-mpeg    MPEG    mpg,mpeg    Ja
audio/mpeg2     MPEG audio  mp2     Ja
audio/x-mpeg2   MPEG audio  mp2     Ja
audio/mp4   MPEG 4 audio    mp4     Ja
audio/x-mp4     MPEG 4 audio    mp4     Ja
video/mp4   MPEG 4 Video    mp4     Ja
video/x-m4v     MPEG 4 Video    m4v     Ja
video/3gpp  MPEG 4 Video    mp4,3gp     Ja
audio/mpeg3     MPEG audio  mp3     Ja
audio/x-mpeg3   MPEG audio  mp3     Ja
audio/x-mpegurl     MPEG url    m3u     Ja
audio/mp3   MPEG audio  mp3     Ja
application/x-ogg   Ogg Vorbis Media    ogg,oga,ogm     Ja
application/ogg     Ogg Vorbis Media    ogg,oga,ogm     Ja
audio/x-ogg     Ogg Vorbis Audio    ogg,oga     Ja
audio/ogg   Ogg Vorbis Audio    ogg,oga     Ja
video/x-ogg     Ogg Vorbis Video    ogg,ogm     Ja
video/ogg   Ogg Vorbis Video    ogg,ogm     Ja
application/x-vlc-plugin    VLC plug-in     vlc     Ja
application/x-google-vlc-plugin     Google VLC plug-in      Ja
audio/flac  FLAC Audio  flac    Ja
audio/x-flac    FLAC Audio  flac    Ja
video/fli   FLI animation   fli,flc     Ja
video/x-fli     FLI animation   fli,flc     Ja
video/x-flv     Flash Video     flv     Ja
video/flv   Flash Video     flv     Ja
video/vnd.vivo  VivoActive  viv,vivo    Ja
audio/x-matroska    Matroska Audio  mka     Ja
video/x-matroska    Matroska Video  mkv     Ja
application/x-nsv-vp3-mp3   Nullsoft Streaming Video    nsv     Ja
audio/x-mod     Soundtracker    mod     Ja
audio/x-aiff    AIFF Audio  aif     Ja
audio/basic     Basic Audio File    au,snd  Ja
audio/x-basic   Basic Audio File    au,snd  Ja
audio/midi  MIDI Audio  mid,midi,kar    Ja
audio/x-scpls   Shoutcast Playlist  pls     Ja
video/x-mng     Multiple-Image Network Graphics     mng     Ja
```

How can i be sure, that the plugin works? I still can't see the video stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Media Player plugin doesn't play video.  It links to Windows Media Player.

Since your Ubuntu system doesn't actually *have* WMP, it won't work, ever.

Try the Xine, Totem, or (my recommendation) VLC plugin instead.

Comment: I'm surprised it even installed.

Comment: @CarlF: thanks for the hint....i've already tried with totem and vlc, but  not with xine.

Comment: @Broam: i think, this is not a "real" WMP-Plugin :)...

Comment: cupakbob, if none of the plugins work for you, you might try posting a new question: "Unable to play video of type <type> on Ubuntu Jaunty system" (adjust to fit your needs).

Comment: The Windows Media plugin on a default Ubuntu system points to Totem. Something is weird here.

Comment: Hmm ... cupakob may need to install the Windows codecs pack, if they're legal in his/her country.